# How to decrease my left window by five characters in vim?

Tags: vim

I have vsplit two windows and make them same width.
Now I want to decrease the left window by five characters and increase the right window by five characters,when the cursor is in the left window, how to input command in normal mode or ex mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to do this in normal and ex-mode.

Let us just show you for your example.

**In normal mode:** `5`followed by  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>w</kbd>  at the same time, this should be finalized by <kbd><</kbd>.

For better experience, you might like to map it to some key,

```
nnoremap <F5> <c-w><
```

This will allow you to press <kbd>F5</kbd> again and again to decrease the size and stop at desired size.

---

**In ex mode:** You can use `:vertical res N`, where N is a absolute number. More details at `:h window-resize`

Comment: <  is equal shift + (.>) ,press tow key.

Answer (score 2):

In general `Ctrl-W` commands do it.

Specifically here `N Ctrl-W <` shrinks the current window by one (or `N` if specified) column and `N Ctrl-W >` extends by one column (or `N` if specified).

Type `:help window-resize` for all related commands.

Comment: For horizontal splits <ctrl>+w+'+' (yeah the plus key) to add a line, <ctrl>+w+'-' (the minus key) remove a line.

Comment: In normal mode, i press 5 then press ctrl w < the three keys at the same time ,nothing happens.

Comment: In ex mode, i press 5 then press ctrl w < the three keys at the same time ,nothing happens. too.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature : You need to press separately - `Ctrl-W` first, and then `<` (without Ctrl).